# change asp.net 2 web service address

Tags: web-services, asp.net-2.0

I'm developing an application that includs a web service, on development time I run the service locally on my pc, than I publish the service to a remote server,
I wanna know how can I take the web reference that I got and just change the address of the service to the remote server to check that every thing is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the service URL usign the Url property:

```
MyWebService.Service1 service = new MyWebService.Service1();
service.Url = NEWSERVICEURL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your Web reference, click properties, and choose Url behavior: Dynamic in properies window. The URL of the Web service will be automatically mapped to a configuration option in the  `Web.config` file that you can change easily, without recompilation:

[image: Screenshot]